# Error in configuring dynamic subdomains for apache2 in ubuntu

Tags: php, .htaccess, ubuntu, apache2

I want to create subdomains for every institute registered on my website.

I carried out following steps to create subdomains for a test website:

> sudo a2enmod vhost_alias
>
> sudo nano /etc/hosts
>
> > add line - 127.0.0.1 test.loc
>
> sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/testloc.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName test.loc
    ServerAlias *.test.loc

    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/html/test

    <Directory "/var/www/html/test">
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

> sudo a2ensite testloc.conf
>
> sudo service apache2 reload
>
> sudo apt-get install dnsmasq
>
> sudo service dnsmasq status
>
> > It gives error that port 53 is already in use so I changed its port to 5353
>
> sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
>
> > added line - dns=dnsmasq
>
> sudo service network-manager restart
>
> sudo nano /etc/dnsmasq.conf
>
> > modified line - listen-address=127.0.0.1
>
> sudo nano /etc/dnsmasq.d/loc
>
> > added line - address=/loc/127.0.0.1
>
> sudo /etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart
>
> sudo nano /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf
>
> > Uncommented line - #prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
>
> sudo dhclient

Created a test folder, added following lines in .htaccess to accept subdomains

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.test\.loc$
RewriteRule !^index\.php$ index.php [L]
```

Code of index.php:

```
preg_match('/([^.]+)\.test\.loc/', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], $matches);
if(isset($matches[1])) {
    $subdomain = $matches[1];
}
echo $subdomain;
```

I tried test.loc before creating Virtual Host and its working. The things were pretty fine before I installed dnsmasq. *dig google.com* is also not working after I installed dnsmasq, but "dig google.com @127.0.0.53" or "dig google.com @8.8.8.8" is also working. So it appears there's some issue with nameservers. Though I checked /etc/resol.conf, nameservers are enlisted there.

But somehow things not working. Can anyone bail me out of this?

Answer (score 0):

After hours of research it can be concluded that Ubuntu 17.04 is not a stable version, so dnsmasq (along with some others) is not working correctly.

I tested above process is working fine on Ubuntu 17.10 without any error.

Thanks